# FabricTransportServiceRemotingClientFactory TraceId -- how to access it on the service side?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, .net-remoting

I have a service fabric project - there is an APIGateway (Facade) that hosts the public webapi layer. It talks to a few different microservices (not exposed publicly) via Fabric Remoting v2.

Now, I want to pass a TraceId (basically HttpContext.TraceIdentifier) from the APIGateway service to the Microservice(s) for tracing/logging purposes. I see that the FabricTransportServiceRemotingClientFactory object (which is the client side svc proxy) takes a TraceId, which is great. However, **how do I access this traceId on the listener side** so that the logger can emit that traceid so I can eventually search for all logs across multiple services for that same Http request using the same traceId.

**APIGateway (client) code**

```
    public MyController()
    {
        // explicitly create V2 remoting client (as listener is V2)
        var proxyFactory = new ServiceProxyFactory((c) =>
        {
            return new FabricTransportServiceRemotingClientFactory(
                traceId: traceIdentifier // <--- from HttpContext, for logging
                );
        });

        _svcProxy = proxyFactory.CreateServiceProxy<IMyService>(
            ServiceUri, 
            listenerName: MyMicroservice.Models.Constants.ListenerName);
    }
```

Comment: If you still need this take a look at [this repo](https://github.com/Expecho/ServiceFabric-Remoting-CustomHeaders) . You can add your own custom message headers containing a self generated trace id for logging purposes

Answer (score 0):

The `ServiceContext` has a property `TraceId`  you can use. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.servicecontext.traceid?view=azure-dotnet)

Example:

```
public sealed class Stateless1 : StatelessService, IStateless1
{
    public Stateless1(StatelessServiceContext context)
        : base(context)
    { }

    public string SayHello()
    {
        return $"Hello World (traceid: {Context.TraceId}";
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new ServiceInstanceListener((c) => new FabricTransportServiceRemotingListener(c, this))
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I wish that would work as expected, but it doesnt. The Context.TraceId in this case is the SAME VALUE that was seeded at the beginning during the Stateless service creation. So even if I pass in a brand new traceid from the client side via "return new FabricTransportServiceRemotingClientFactory(
                traceId: traceIdentifier // <--- from HttpContext, for logging
                );" call, on the service side, it will still hold on to the very first  traceid it received. :(

Comment: To be clear, what I'd like is for the traceid to be the value that I pass in from the new FabricTransportServiceRemotingClientFactory( traceId: traceIdentifier call. So it changes for every remoting call made (as a result of httpcontext.traceidentifier changing)